# AD replication stops

Tags: active-directory, replication

i have a domain controller located in a distance site which has a replication problem. Replication stops after a small period of time (about half an hour). The only way to resolve it is to change the IP address of the server. Then it works for a while and after that it stops again. 
While it can't replicate, Dfsr is returning errors and Ldp.exe is unable to establish connection to other domain controllers. However, internet connection is working. 
DNS for this server is the domain controller i want to be replicated. I have tried with two different domain controllers but without luck.
When the replication issue occurs, i am able to ping the remote server by name and nslookup is working without a problem. 
I just want to understand if this is caused by the firewall (hardware) or if it could be an operating or Active Directory issue. If anyone can shed some light that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. It was caused by MTU. I pinged the primary domain controller using `ping -f -l 1400` and I found that MTU was smaller. I adjusted it and everything worked like a charm.